# Meta's "How to Ask" links to FAQ

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions, meta, help-center

When you first start to ask a question on Meta (or if you simply select the title field), this text appears:
[image: META HTA]

Since the *faq* has been turned into the *help center*, shouldn't this contain links to "*visit the help center*" / "*asking help*" just like it is on SO?
[image: SO HTA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expected this to require site-by-site edits, but thankfully this issue got attention of SE employees. The issue has been resolved via 'extreme SQL'. See [this answer](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/720/5454) for details.